# INSERT TIMESTAMP or DATETIME fails when month, day, hour or min is 8 or 9

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp, sql-insert

I'm having a strange problem while dealing with inserting datetime values. it happens while inserting DATETIME or TIMESTAMP type columns, as well as when using STR_TO_DATE function.

it seems that the database cannot parse correctly when the month, the day, the hour or the minute are number 8 or 9. Some examples:

```
INSERT INTO test(date) VALUES("2018-01-07 10:08:47");
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | date                |
+----+---------------------+
|  7 | 2018-01-07 10:00:00 |
+----+---------------------+
```

Now with the day

```
INSERT INTO test(date) VALUES("2018-01-08 10:47:47");
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | date                |
+----+---------------------+
|  3 | 2018-01-00 8:00:00  |
+----+---------------------+
```

The month also fails:

```
INSERT INTO test(date) VALUES("2018-09-07 10:47:47");
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | date                |
+----+---------------------+
|  9 | 2018-00-00 0:00:00  |
+----+---------------------+
```

When the values are different from 8 or 9 the insert is succesful:

```
INSERT INTO test(date) VALUES("2018-01-07 10:47:08")
```

Result:

```
+----+---------------------+
| id | date                |
+----+---------------------+
|  8 | 2018-01-07 10:47:08 |
+----+---------------------+
```

This is the description of the table:

```
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field | Type      | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id    | int(11)   | NO   | PRI | null              | auto_increment              |
| date  | timestamp | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+-------+-----------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I also tested this problem with the STR_TO_DATE function, having the same results:

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("10/08/2018 7:47:25", "%d/%m/%Y %k:%i:%s");

+--------------------------------------------------------+
| STR_TO_DATE("10/08/2018 7:47:25", "%d/%m/%Y %k:%i:%s") |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
| 2018-00-00 0:00:00                                     |
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Some ideas?. I really need it stored in data related format, not in a string.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Please show us the table definitions.  Also include a demo if possible to make this question reproducible.

Comment: please add table schema

Comment: Do you mean the description of the columns? There is not much to show, just the inserts. THe result are just a the desired row  of "SELECT * FROM test;"

Comment: Modify this example until you can replicate your problem...  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/775cee

Comment: I'm not able to replicate in that example sadly. it's clear that the problem is with my database. I'm running version 5.7.20 however

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why the date type you choosed is 'timestamp'. Why can't you use simply 'datetime' ?

If you can't change try `INSERT INTO test(date) VALUES unix_timestamp("2018-09-07 10:47:47");`

I created an example on a windows machine running MySQL 5.7.19:

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `test_date` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_field` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

then insert:

```
INSERT INTO test_date(date_field) VALUES("2018-09-07 10:47:47");
```

final result:

```
id  date_field
1   2018-09-07 10:47:47
```

Comment: I also tested with datetime format before, same result.

Comment: The date_field inserted with your commands  is: 2018-00-00 0:00:00

Comment: I guess I will try to reinstall mysql

Comment: Edit: The fail is only in the Mysql shell SELECT results visualization, I thought it was due to the version, because this last time, I did the query in the MySQL workbench, which shows the results correctly. It is a bug of mysql shell visualization

Answer (score 0):

Annoyingly, I can't comment cause I don't have enough rep.

I'm also seeing the same issue. Running MySQL version 5.7.20.

```
INSERT INTO users (user_id, created_at) VALUES ('user_1', '2018-01-08 21:31:32');
```

This results in the value `2018-01-00 8:00:00` in the table.

Can confirm that the value `2018-01-07 21:31:32` does correctly get inserted as `2018-01-07 21:31:32`.

I have seen the issue with inserts through both SQLAlchemy and the MySQL shell to the same database/table.

Comment: I have found that it is a problem of visualization, since I have checked that the data is stored correctly.I don't know if there is a solution to this bug in the visualization of SELECT results of these tools.

Comment: Sounds good, I tested it as well and yeah the actual values appear to be fine when I read them back via SQLAlchemy. Just the display of them in mysqlsh on Mac OS is the issue. I've submitted a bug report here, not sure if anything will come of it: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=89144